# Redis timeout error for Asp.Net Application using StackExchange.Redis 4.0.1 nuget package

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am having legacy Asp.Net WebForm application based on .Net Framework 4.6.1. Currently session is managed  using SQL server which adds a lot of load on SQL server. To overcome this issue, I have decided to move the session management from SQL server to Redis server.

Application is hosted on premise. Application server and Redis server are hosted in the same network to avoid the network latency.
This is working fine in most of the cases however many a times I am getting timeout errors from Redis.

**Redis Version** - 5.0.5 hosted on premise

I am using  **Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider** 4.0.1 nuget package in the application. I observed the following errors multiple times

**RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate
0116975
  Caught StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException Timeout performing EVAL (20000ms), inst: 0, qs: 69, in: 0, serverEndpoint: Internal IP:6380, mgr: 9 of 10 available, clientName: ****, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=62,Free=32705,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.519.65453 (Please**

Following settings are used in web.config to connect to Redis server

```
<add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="some IP" port="6379" ssl="false" 
        throwOnError = "true"  connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="20000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="20000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="21000"/>
```

I have increased timeout value to 20000 ms but still timeout error is occurring.

Comment: I think you should locate when it is timing out? Is the requested object too big? Check the event logs seek the exact time exception occurs see if anything else happening in that time

Comment: @Eldar, Issue is not specific to big request. Issue is occurring during load testing. When 50 or more users are hitting the application using Jmeter, some of the requests are failing. It is failing for small or big Redis request when the load testing is happening.
Redis server and application server are hosted in the same intranet environment. CPU utilization of Redis and application server is normal.

Comment: How you create your connections? I had similar issues when i was creating so many connections.

Comment: I am not creating connection explicitly. It is all handled by nuget package Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.  Please refer to setting mentioned in the question where I have mentioned timeout and other parameters